# Java Rock Paper Scissors

Tags: java

looked at the other thread but I could not figure out why my program after i input my choice i.e. Rock The program either gives 2 answers or none at all. I know its similar to a previous thread but I don't understand why the reply varies. Any help would be appreciated.

```
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class RockPaperScissors {

public static void main(String[] args) {
System.out.println("Do you want to play Rock Paper Sissors?");
System.out.println("Yes or No?");
Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
String input = scan.nextLine();             
if (input.equals("Yes")){
    System.out.println("OK pick your weapon!");
    String weapon = scan.nextLine();
    Random rand = new Random();
    rand.nextInt(3);
    if (rand.nextInt(3) == 0){
    //*0=Rock
        if (weapon.equals("Rock")) {
            System.out.println("I choose Rock, so did you... tie.");                    
        }
        else if (weapon.equals("Paper")){
            System.out.println("I choose Rock and you choose Paper...You Win :( !");
        }
        else if (weapon.equals("Scissors")){
            System.out.println("I choose Rock and you choose Paper...You Lose :) !");
        }               
    }
    if (rand.nextInt(3) == 1){
    //*1=Paper
        if (weapon.equals("Rock")) {
            System.out.println("I choose Paper and you choose Rock...You Lose :)  !");                  
        }
        else if (weapon.equals("Paper")){
            System.out.println("I choose Paper, so did you...tie.");
        }
        else if (weapon.equals("Scissors")){
            System.out.println("I choose Paper and you choose Scissors...You Win :(      !");
        }               
    }
    if (rand.nextInt(3) == 2){
        //*2=Scissors
            if (weapon.equals("Rock")) {
                System.out.println("I choose Scissors and you choose Rock...You Win :(    !");                    
            }
            else if (weapon.equals("Paper")){
                System.out.println("I choose Scissors and you choose Paper...You Lose:) !");
            }
            else if (weapon.equals("Scissors")){
                System.out.println("I choose Scissors, so did you...tie.");
            }               
        }
    }
else {
    System.out.println("OK have a nice day.");
}
}

}
```

Thanks for helping.

Comment: Have you learned what a debugger is?

Comment: Try taking some pen and paper and sketching out the execution of your program.

Answer (score 2):

You have three if statements each generating their own random value, so it's possible for all three if statements to be executed. You should save off the result of rand.nextInt(3) once, and use that in the three consecutive if statements. I would change the three if statements in a row to a series of if/else if statements as well.

You seem to almost have the correct solution down where you call

```
rand.nextInt(3);
```

once before the initial if statements, just save that result to a variable.